# Handling NULL characters in shell

Tags: shell, binary

Is there a portable way of handling NULL characters in shell?

A typical example would be splitting the output of `find ... -print0` with shell (and shell only) either in a pipe or in a command substitution result. By portable I mean ideally something that shells not as powerful as e.g. `bash` or `zsh` wouldn't choke on. Is this possible in a "bare POSIX shell" (any POSIX version)?

Comment: heirloom-sh flunks this feature request, as far as I can tell.

Comment: You might want to use the intersection `ksh` (smallest of the three, I think) `bash` and `zsh`, or you could use `xargs -0` (and execute shells on each argument) or you could do some ugly encoding/decoding of \0 with a random \n terminated sequence, or do checking for existence and coalescing, or you could tell your users that your program will choke if their filenames have newlines in them (I'm particularly in favor of the last suggestion :) ).

Comment: @PSkocik I agree. My main motivation is a script that checks various things about system files - and having those names contain anything else than English letters, Arabic numerals and couple of punctuation signs (like dot, underscore etc.) is already quite unlikely and IMHO bordering on crazy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

POSIX doesn't envision the standard utilities to deal with text embedding `null` characters. The `-print0` option you use with `find` is itself a `GNU` extension unsupported by `POSIX`.

One way to deal with a flow of data containing `null`s with `POSIX` shell scripting would be to convert it first to real text with `od` and process that text instead.

In any case, if you have `GNU find`, you likely have other `GNU` utilities that haven't that limitation in the first place.

Comment: Yes, for my particular problem it is reasonable to assume being in the GNU ecosystem. But then it is also reasonable to assume sane file names. :)

Comment: That is a of the flaw in POSIX.

Answer (score 2):

Bash can handle it using `read`'s `-d` option, e.g.

```
find . -print0 | while read -r -d '' line; do
    # something with $line
done
```

No idea if that's POSIX, though.

Comment: I'm aware of that and AFAICT it is not: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html.

Comment: I see. Well, if bash isn't available, I don't have any better ideas.

Answer (score 1):

After [finding a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398393/identifying-and-removing-null-characters-in-unix), here is what I have come up with after some time...not sure if this is doable in a POSIX shell. Tried this in Cygwin. Just for fun, made up a problem with null chars.

The imaginary problem is the following: you have (some) files that have null characters in them. You do not know exactly which files those are or where they are located. Your given task is to get rid of null characters of all such possible files.

Below, first command will show you the lines that have null characters, then another command converts nulls to newlines (the last one removes the temporary file):

```
find . ! -type d -exec perl -ne '/\000/ and print;' {} \; > /tmp/null-lines
tr -s '\000' '\n' < /tmp/null-lines > with-null-lines.txt
rm /tmp/null-lines
```

After that, it's a matter of reading each line of the result lines and finding to which file does a line belong. For this, I first save all the files I need to go through, then see if there is a line matching in them:

```
find . ! -type d -print > files.txt
while read line; do while read line2; do if grep -q "$line2" "$line"; then echo "$line" >> examination.txt; fi; done < with-null-lines.txt; done < files.txt
```

(Before rerunning the cycle, remove the file "examination.txt")

Now, we count the number of occurrences, and where there are more than 1, chances are it has more than one null character (sure, if there is only one, it becomes more painful to find).

```
uniq -c examination.txt | grep -v "1"
```

And there it should list (most) files containing null characters. Ignore the "with-null-lines.txt" one. Also, if there are identical texts in files, then you may also see some innocent files in there that need manual purging from the list.

1. If the null chars are not in the place of newlines, just simply remove them:

   ```
   uniq -d examination.txt > files-to-clean.txt
   while read line; do ex -s +"%s/\%x00//g" -cwq $line; done < files-to-clean.txt
   ```

   Or with `tr`, for a file:

   ```
   tr -d '\000' < inputfile > outputfile
   ```
2. To clean a file from null chars (provided they are all located in place of newlines), use the command:

   ```
   tr -s '\000' '\n' < inputfile > outputfile
   ```

   Did not look too much into how you could process many files with `tr` at once.

Comment: -1 - I'm not really sure how this answers my question. The answer to your hypothetical problem is to run `tr -d '\000'` on all files in question (regardless of whether they do contain any NULL bytes or not). Not to mention that what you are describing will run into problems in many cases.